# Difference in randomForestSRC and randomForest package / increasing OOB-Error curve

Tags: r, random-forest

Probably this is related to [randomForest vs randomForestSRC discrepancies](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190911/randomforest-vs-randomforestsrc-discrepancies).

When training this dataset it seems, that concerning the mean missclassification error less trees are better than more in the R-package RandomForestSRC. Is there a specific reason for this? Until now I thought that more trees are always better.

```
# Installation of OpenML
install.packages(c("mlr", "checkmate", "data.table", "digest", "RCurl", "stringi", "XML", "RWeka", "devtools"))
devtools::install_github("openml/r")   
library(OpenML)
saveOMLConfig(apikey = "put_here_your_key_from_openml.org")

task = getOMLTask(task.id = 3595, verbosity=0) 
library(randomForestSRC)  
run = matrix(NA, 1000, 2000)  
set.seed(105)
for(i in 1:1000){
  print(paste(i))
  run[i,] = rfsrc(binaryClass ~., data = task$input$data.set$data, ntree = 2000, importance="none", mtry=2, nodesize = 1)$err.rate[,1]
}
runs = apply(run, 2, mean)
quant1 = apply(run, 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.25))
quant2 = apply(run, 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.75))
plot(runs, type="l", ylim = c(min(runs, quant1, quant2), max(runs,quant1, quant2)))
lines(1:2000, quant1, col = "red")
lines(1:2000, quant2, col = "green")
```

[image]

I tried to calculate the same thing with randomForest package, but the results were quite different. Here the curve continues to decrease with adding more trees.

```
library(randomForest)
run = matrix(NA, 1000, 2000)  
set.seed(105)
for(i in 1:1000){
  print(paste(i))
  run[i,] = randomForest(binaryClass ~., data = task$input$data.set$data, ntree = 2000, mtry=2, nodesize = 1)$err.rate[,1]
}
runs = apply(run, 2, mean)
quant1 = apply(run, 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.25))
quant2 = apply(run, 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.75))
plot(runs, type="l", ylim = c(min(runs, quant1, quant2), max(runs,quant1, quant2)))
lines(1:2000, quant1, col = "red")
lines(1:2000, quant2, col = "green")
```

[image]

edit: A growing Errorrate-curve is also possible with the randomForest package. See this example:

```
library(OpenML)
task = getOMLTask(task.id = 3548, verbosity=0) 
library(randomForest)
run = matrix(NA, 1000, 2000)  
set.seed(108)
for(i in 1:1000){
  print(paste(i))
  run[i,] = randomForest(Type ~., data = task$input$data.set$data, ntree = 2000)$err.rate[,1]
}
runs = apply(run, 2, mean)
quant1 = apply(run, 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.25))
quant2 = apply(run, 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.75))
plot(runs, type="l", ylim = c(min(runs, quant1, quant2), max(runs,quant1, quant2)))
lines(1:2000, quant1, col = "red")
lines(1:2000, quant2, col = "green")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution to the problem, see the code below.

With more trees (e.g.3000), RF is more sure about the classification in a specific class, in comparison with RF with 100 trees. 
So in some specific data cases this can lead to the case, that RF with 3000 trees is always wrong while RF with 100 trees sometimes is correct.

The underlying problem is also, that not probabilities are considered but only the most probable case in the majority vote (as well in the trees as in the whole forest).

```
library(OpenML)
task = getOMLTask(task.id = 3548, verbosity=0) 
library(randomForest)
set.seed(108)

preds = list(matrix(NA, 200, 27), matrix(NA, 200, 27))
set.seed(123)
for (i in 1:200){
  print(i)
  preds[[1]][i,] = randomForest(Type ~., data = task$input$data.set$data, ntree = 100)$predicted
  preds[[2]][i,] = randomForest(Type ~., data = task$input$data.set$data, ntree = 3000)$predicted
}

sum(apply(preds[[1]], 2, function(x) names(table(x))[which(table(x) == max(table(x)))] ) == apply(preds[[2]], 2, function(x) names(table(x))[which(table(x) == max(table(x)))] ))

erg = list(matrix(NA, 27, 4), matrix(NA, 27, 4))
for (i in 1:4){
  for (j in 1:27){
    erg[[1]][j, i] = sum(preds[[1]][, j] == i)
    erg[[2]][j, i] = sum(preds[[2]][, j] == i)
  }
}

erg_ges = data.frame(erg[[1]], erg[[2]], task$input$data.set$data$Type)
colnames(erg_ges) = c(paste("100", c("a","b","c","o")), paste("3000", c("a","b","c","o")), "real_value")
erg_ges
   #    100 a 100 b 100 c 100 o 3000 a 3000 b 3000 c 3000 o real_value
#1     88     5   107     0     18      0    182      0          a
#2    173    27     0     0    200      0      0      0          a
#3    200     0     0     0    200      0      0      0          a
#4     84   116     0     0     45    155      0      0          a
#5      4   196     0     0      0    200      0      0          a
#6    176    24     0     0    200      0      0      0          a
#7      2   198     0     0      0    200      0      0          b
#8    199     1     0     0    200      0      0      0          b
#9    103    97     0     0    152     48      0      0          b
#10     0   200     0     0      0    200      0      0          b
#11     0   200     0     0      0    200      0      0          b
#12     0     0   200     0      0      0    200      0          b
#13     2   198     0     0      0    200      0      0          b
#14     0   200     0     0      0    200      0      0          b
#15     3   197     0     0      0    200      0      0          b
#16     0   198     2     0      0    200      0      0          b
#17     0     2   198     0      0      0    200      0          c
#18     0    10   190     0      0      0    200      0          c
#19     0   171    29     0      0    200      0      0          c
#20     0    94    66    40      0    188     12      0          c
#21     0    23   177     0      0      0    200      0          c
#22     5   195     0     0      0    200      0      0          b
#23     0   107    93     0      0    134     66      0          c
#24     0   198     1     1      0    200      0      0          b
#25   198     2     0     0    200      0      0      0          a
#26    31   155     0    14      0    200      0      0          o
#27     0   200     0     0      0    200      0      0          o
```